# EKAlarms with relativeOffset

Tags: ios, eventkit

I'm currently trying to write a method to compare `EKAlarms` to one another.  The problem with this is between `absoluteDate` and `relativeOffset`.  Comparing two alarms each with an `absoluteDate` is easy, but if one or both have a `relativeOffset`, you need to know what event they're relatively offset from.  As per the documentation,

> relativeOffset: The offset from the start of an event, at which the alarm fires.

Yet, I see no documentation on setting the trigger for a `relativeOffset` alarm. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing?  How can I compare two EKAlarms with `relativeOffsets`?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you rightly say:

> if one or both have a `relativeOffset`, you need to know what event they're relatively offset from

Quite so. But how can you possibly *not* know that? EKAlarms do not float around loose, falling from the sky like snowflakes. If not attached to an EKCalendarItem, a relative EKAlarm is meaningless; there is nothing to compare. If it *is* attached to an EKCalendarItem, then you clearly know that fact - otherwise, where would you have gotten the alarm from??? Either you just created the alarm, and are about to attach it to an EKCalendarItem yourself, or you have started with the EKCalendarItem and have looked at its `alarms` property, in which case you also know the EKCalendarItem's `startDate` and can calculate from there.

Comment: Ah, it seems I've misunderstood the meaning of "an event." I read it to mean that it was offset from the start of "some thing that happens" as opposed to "an EKEvent."  And I'm sure that means offset from a reminder's dueDate property in that case.  Still, hopefully Apple will revise the documentation to something a little less ambiguous. Anyway, Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: I do not actually know how a relative alarm relates to an EKReminder - is it taken from the start date or the due date? You might need to experiment to determine this.